# is any way to abort AjaxBehaviorEvent listener or pass additional info to f:ajax onevent?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf

I have created listener in my controller, something like that..

```
public class FooController {
    public void doSomething(AjaxBehaviorEvent evt) {
        closeDialogFlag = true;
        ..
        if(!isValid){
            closeDialogFlag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And my JSF button..

```
<h:commandButton value="Do somenthing">
    <f:ajax 
        listener="#{fooController.doSomething}"
        execute=":editDialogForm:processTab" render="@this :editDialogForm:processTab :messageViewer:messageViewerPanel :results"
        onevent="function(data){ if(data.status === 'success' &amp;&amp; #{fooController.closeDialogFlag} ) { $('#migrationEditDialogModal').modal('hide'); } }"
    />
</h:commandButton>
```

But my `closeDialogFlag` doesn't work after ajax request is completed, bacause value `#{fooController.closeDialogFlag}` is extracted when page is loading and is not updated after AJAX request. I need to refresh a page to see new value in output code.

**The question is**:
How can I pass additional information to `data` in `onevent=function(data)` in my listener? (This solution is more appropriate to me because it will be useful in various cases) **OR** Is any way to abort my request in my listener and force my AJAX request to return another status than `success`?

PS: I don't want use Primefaces, Richfaces etc.

**Edit**:
small correction.
If i add to my `f:ajax` to attribute `render` value `@this`, than my flag is extracted successful as `true` but in fact after my AJAX request my dialog is not hidding by  JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little trick for your specific problem:

1. Create a `<h:inputHidden id="closeDialogFlag" value="#{fooController.closeDialogFlag}"/>` in the same `<h:form>` as your `<h:commandButton ... />`. Here, I suppose `#{fooController.closeDialogFlag}` is of type `boolean`.
2. In your f:ajax:

   1. Render the component `closeDialogFlag`.
   2. Change your condition in the onevent to: `function(data){ if(data.status === 'success' &amp;&amp; $('input#closeDialogFlag').val() === 'true') { $('#migrationEditDialogModal').modal('hide'); } }`

You will have to change `$('input#closeDialogFlag')` to point to the correct ID (will depend on the parents' id).

This works because when `data.status === 'success'`, the components are already rendered with their new values.

Comment: I did it in the same way and it works and solved my problem. But imo better solution would be pass something from listener to JavaScript function which is call in `onevent`, have you any idea how to do it? I tried googling but I did not find anything useful. But still done is better than perfect, thanks for your help.

Comment: You do can pass extra parameter to the `onevent` (and `onerror`), but **not an EL expression** (as far as I know) `onevent="function (data) { myFunction(data, 'extra 1', 'extra 2'); }"`

Comment: Yes, but in that way I can pass only arguments in JS, not derived from listener. Thanks anyway for your time. Best regards.