# Javascript popup or EJB container call

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, ejb

I am mostly developing java backend, but I learnt some very basic javascript at university although I would not say, that I am an expert in it. Now I run into a problem, and I tried to look up the proper solution, but I think I am missing some well-known expressions during search because I did not find anything useful.

I am using JSF and java. I have a table: in each row I have an input field (e.g. name) and a button. If I click on the button I would like to check if the name is unique. If it is not, than I want a popup window to come up, and if it is I want to call the EJB function.

So long I have written something like the following:

```
<h:commandButton value ="button"
            id="button"
            rendered="#{name.modified}" 
            >
            <f:ajax 
                listener="#{controller.ejbFunction(person)}"
                onevent="function(event){jsFunction('#{mitarbeiter}', event); return;}"     
                render="@all" // I know it is not proper I will use something else instead
                execute="@all"/>                            
        </h:commandButton>
```

The java function (other functions work from this class)

```
  public boolean isNameUnique(person){
    if(person == null || person.name == null){
      return false;
    }
    return checkIfNameUnique();
  }
```

The javascript function

```
function jsFunction(person, event){
        if (event.status == 'begin'){
        var nameIsUnique = #{EJBClass.nameUnique(person)};
             if(!validationOk){
                $('ldNotUniqueNameErrorDialogHelper').click();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

My problem comes with the

```
var nameIsUnique = #{Controller.nameUnique(person)};
```

row. I used it, because in one of the other js functions in our code it is also used, but it does not seem to work for me, it always gives back false. If I put a debugg point into the function it does not stop. I tried to look up if it is possible to do something like this, and I come up with nothing. Is it possible to do it like this? If not than what would be the easiest way to implement something like this?

I thought that I could do it like the following (and maybe I will), but is this some widely accepted solution): [is any way to abort AjaxBehaviorEvent listener or pass additional info to f:ajax onevent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350593/is-any-way-to-abort-ajaxbehaviorevent-listener-or-pass-additional-info-to-fajax?rq=1)

It really seems like hacking for me (maybe because I am not used to JS development).

Thank you, and sorry if the post is redundant!

Comment: The syntax `#{anything}` will be seen only by the rendering engine at your server (JSF). The javascript code runs in the browser after the fully rendered page was sent to the browser. There is noone, whos looking for `#{anything}`

Comment: You are right, it does not make much sense. So there is not any version/library of js, which makes some kind of ajax code or something from #{code}? Because in this case we use this syntax like 20 places incorrectly, which seems weird, because some of the instances are older than a year. Thanks for your answer!